# getting a telegram to respond to new users (ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bots, telegram

I am trying to code the telegram bot in ruby, to recognize new_chat_members, as well as responding to commands, at the moment the bot works fine it just does not recognize new members and instead responds with the else command.

Does anyone have any solutions or a work around?

```
require 'telegram_bot'

bot = TelegramBot.new(token: 'token api')
bot.get_updates(fail_silently: true) do |message|
puts "@#{message.from.username}: #{message.text}"

command = message.get_command_for(bot)

  message.reply do |reply|
    case command
    when /start/i
      reply.text = "Hi Try /help for command list."
    when /help/i 
      reply.text = "A list of commands that you can use.

     /greet - greets new users.  

     /website - Provides a link to the Connect Platform.

    /price - Displays current price.

    /supply - Total circulating supply."
    when /greet/i
      reply.text = "Hello, #{message.from.first_name}.  Welcome to Connect 
      telegram, If you need any /help just ask."
    when /website/i
      reply.text = "welcome, #{message.from.first_name} to the Connect 
      Platform."
    when /price/i
      reply.text = "Current price of 
    when /supply/i
      reply.text = "Circulating supply.
    when /hi/i
      reply.text = "Hi, #{message.from.first_name} Welcome to Connect 
      telegram, If you need any /help just ask."        
    if 
      reply.text = "Hi, #{message.from.new_chat_member}Welcome to the 
      connect telegram channel"
    end
    else  
      reply.text = "Hi, #{message.from.first_name} I do not know what # 
      {command.inspect} means, try /help for command list"
   end
      puts "sending #{reply.text.inspect} to @#{message.from.username}"
      reply.send_with(bot) 
   end
 end
```

Comment: I have missed out a couple " where i pasted the code over.

what i am struggling with is the if command section (new_chat_members).

Comment: 1-what kind of `if` is that!?
2-you can't get new chat members like this.

Comment: it is to greet new chat members.. not add them